# Values are not showing in a form input AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, html

[Console screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVL6s.png) I'm having a problem with my code; I'm getting values upon clicking the button, and the same values are also showing in the console. However, I can't see the same values in the input field. Can anyone help with this?

```
$scope.getFees = function (id) {
  getClients.getFeesPoints(id).then(function(response) {
    $scope.fees = response.data.fees;            
    console.log($scope.fees);                    
  });    
};  
<input type="text" ng-model="fees" class="mdltb-inp fee-inp"
       name="fees"  placeholder="35$" >
```

Check link of image 30 is the value of response data

Comment: Change value="{{user}}" to ng-value="fees"

Comment: no that's not the problem here.

Comment: Then u should check what your fees variable contains

Comment: `console.log($scope.fees); ` what do you get in console?

Comment: i hv edited my code plz check it

Comment: it is showing only value like 30 ..that is true in db for this id

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Try stringifying $scope.fees= JSON.stringify(response.data.fees) @ravneet

Answer (score 0):

Remove `value="{{User}}"` from the code and verify `$scope.fees = response.data;` binds a text value and not an object.

In case if the `response.data` is an object, that won't bind to an input text field. Find out the appropriate key from `response.data` object and bind input with that key. Also if the value is not binded still try to call `$scope.$apply()` after assigning the value

Comment: it is showing the value in console..example : 30. but not displaying on field

Answer (score 0):

I this you should try this way

```js
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.fees="new";
  
  $scope.getFees = function (id) {

//getClients.getFeesPoints(id).then(function(response)
    //{
  $scope.fees = 50;            
  console.log($scope.fees);  

    //});    

};  
  
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp">  
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputValue" name="uservalue" ng-model="fees" ng-required="true" autofocus="true" ng-blur="checkIfValid()"/>
    <button ng-click="getFees(true)">Demo</button>
    <h1>{{fees}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is not sending data to the html file

Comment: you can try with  $timeout(function(),{ //set value into scope }, 2000);

Answer (score 0):

I have Solved this by using $rootScope i.e. "$rootScope” is a parent object of all “$scope” angular objects created in a web page.